# How to press keys on Android application in Appium via Robot Framework?

Tags: appium, robotframework

my Robot Framework script is shown below. When I use the "Input Text" keyword, the previous letters are erased and only the last letter is shown. How can I simulate a manual key press using Appium via Robot Framework?

```
*** Settings ***
Library          AppiumLibrary
Test Setup       Setup application
Test Teardown    Teardown application

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER_NAME}          mobileOS
${PLATFORM}              Android
${USER}                  XXXXXXX
${PASSWORD}              XXXXXXX
${deviceName}            XXXXXXX
${AUTOMATIONNAME}        Appium
${HOST}                  https://XXXX.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub
${ANDROID_APP}           PUBLIC:XXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXX_X_X_XX.apk
${ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE}   XXX.XXX
${APP_ACTIVITY}          XXX.XXX.XXX

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 01: Open application and then close it
    Log Source
    Wait until page contains element    xpath=//*[@resource-id='email']    timeout=60
    Input Text    xpath=//*[@resource-id='email']    Hello
    Capture Page Screenshot

*** Keywords ***
Setup application
    Open Application    ${HOST}
    ...                 browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}
    ...                 platform=${PLATFORM}
    ...                 user=${USER}
    ...                 password=${PASSWORD}
    ...                 deviceName=${DEVICENAME}
    ...                 automationName=${AUTOMATION_NAME}
    ...                 app=${ANDROID_APP}
    ...                 appPackage=${ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE}
    ...                 appActivity=${APP_ACTIVITY}

Teardown application
    Log Source
    Close Application
```

Comment: What version of Appium are you using?

Comment: Hi **econoMicahel**, here's what I have:
(1) `Appium-Python-Client (0.21)` (2) `robotframework-appiumlibrary (1.3.5)`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but I meant for the server. Sorry I wasn't clear before.

Comment: Hi **econoMichael**, I've tried to do an HTTP GET (https://XXXX.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/wd/hub/status) on the remote server (I'm using Perfecto Mobile's cloud device) and here's the JSON response I got: **{"sessionId":null,"status":0,"state":"success","value":{"build":{"version":"2.48.2","revision":"41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67","time":"2015-10-09 13:08:06"},"os":{"name":"Windows Server 2008 R2","arch":"amd64","version":"6.1"},"java":{"version":"1.7.0_51"}},"class":"org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response","hCode":1260495280}**

Comment: Hi Ryan, unfortunately that information doesn't give me the version of the Appium server. However, I can say that older versions of Appium have had issues with Android input. See these: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/3839 https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-appium-1-2-2-sendkeys-issue-with-hinted-edit-text/309 and I'm sure you can find more on Google.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it would be of any help. I'll try to contact perfecto mobile to check what version is their Appium server. Meanwhile, I'll try tweaking Robot's AppiumLibrary and see if there's something that can be done there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selenium library built-in keyword Press Key along with the corresponding ASCII code of the certain key you want to press.

For more information visit: https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Press%20Keycode

Example:

```
press keycode           66
```